# Updating an input value is updating all the corresponding input values in the array in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my JS code.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("myController", [function () {
    this.master = [];

    this.addUser = function(user) {
                this.master.push(user)
    };

    this.removeUser = function(user) {
        var indexToRemove = this.master.indexOf(user);
        this.master.splice(indexToRemove,1)
    }

    this.reset = function() {
        this.user = this.master[this.master.length - 1];
    }

}])
```

Here is my HTML part.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as Cntrl">
    <form>
        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /> <br />
        Email: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /> <br />
        Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" /> Male
        <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" /> female <br /> <br />

        <input type="button" ng-click="Cntrl.addUser(user)" value="Add User">  

        <input type="button" ng-click="Cntrl.reset()" value="Reset User"> 

    </form>

    <div ng-repeat="users in Cntrl.master track by $index">
         <span ng-click="Cntrl.removeUser(users)" >X</span> <pre>{{users | json}}</pre>

    </div>

</body>
```

I am able to add new users and remove the selected users. But whenever I add any new users, the properties of all the old users in the array are getting updated with the properties of the newly added user.

Please explain the mistake I am making here.

Answer (score 0):

all users pushed into array are the same one, and remove better use index,
         ng-click="Cntrl.removeUser($index)"

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("myController", [
    function() {
      this.master = [];
      this.user = this;

      //use this.user
      this.addUser = function() {
        this.master.push(this.user)
        this.user = {}
      };

      //use index
      this.removeUser = function(index) {
        this.master.splice(indexToRemove, 1)
      }

      this.reset = function() {
        this.user = this.master[this.master.length - 1];
      }

    }
  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

you are giving user  reference  to master array , and because of two way data binding your values are updated , can u try this,  will work.

just modify your addUser method as below.

```
     this.addUser = function(user) {
        this.master.push(angular.copy(user));
    };
```

angular copy will create  deep copy of object , see docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Answer (score 0):

> As there has already been 3 posts that answers your question. But I
>   guess there are some serious logical misunderstanding on the VM
>   approach your are trying to implement in your code. Though the program
>   is now working but I highly recommend you to go through the John
>   Papa's tutorial before proceeding with your solution. This would clear
>   your fundamentals and make you understand why it wasn't working
>   before.

https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/